# Search and Display Contents of ArrayList from Text File

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, delimiter

I have created a Song class that includes data members for a Song (Title, artist, album). I already have a .txt file that  contains different songs which is stored into an array list. In my main class one of the functions is to allow the user to search for a song by either title, artist, or album.

My problem is that the search function does not find the song when the user inputs certain titles. For example, when I Search for the song title "Stay" it finds it. But, when I search for the song titled "Bohemian Rhapsody" it can't find it stored. I know it is stored because when i display the list it shows up. This problem also occurs when searching by album or artist.

I think my problem is occurring due to the way I split the String or maybe its just a problem with the search function itself.

**This is my Song class with Constructor and Get/Set Methods**

```
public class Song {
    //Declaring all data members.
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private String album;
    private String length;
    private static int songCounter = 0;

    //Constructors for Song class.      
    public Song(String title, String artist, String album, String length){
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.album = album;
        this.length = length;
        songCounter++;
    }
    //Get and Set methods 
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getArtist(){
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getAlbum(){
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album){
        this.album = album;
    }

    public String getLength(){
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(String length){
        this.length = length;
    }

    public static int getSongCounter(){
        return songCounter;
    }
    //Overriding the toString() function.
    public String toString(){
        return title +" "+artist+" "+album+" "+length;
    }
 }
```

**This is my Main class which reads from .txt file and includes Search method**

```
public class Library {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList <Song> songList = new ArrayList <Song> ();
    boolean testInput = true;

    try{
        Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("SongList.txt"));
        do{
            String line = read.nextLine();
            String [] tokens = line.split(",");
            songList.add(new Song(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3]));
        }while(read.hasNext());
        read.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }

    while ( testInput ){
        System.out.println("\nSelect a Function");
        System.out.println("1. Search Song");
        System.out.println("2. Add Song");
        System.out.println("3. Delete Song");
        System.out.println("4. Display Songs");
        System.out.println("5. Quit");

        switch (MenuInputCheck(1, 5)){

        case 1: searchSong(songList);
                break;
        case 2: addSong(songList);
                break;
        case 3: deleteSong(songList);
                break;
        case 4: displaySong(songList);
                break;
        case 5: testInput = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public static void searchSong(ArrayList <Song> songList){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("A. Search by Title");
    System.out.println("B. Search by Artist");
    System.out.println("C. Search by Album");

    boolean found = false;
    char menuOption = input.next().charAt(0);

    switch (menuOption) {
    case 'A':
    case 'a': System.out.print("Enter song title: ");
              String searchTitle = input.nextLine();
              for (Song i : songList){
                  if (i.getTitle().equals(searchTitle)){
                      System.out.println(i);
                      found = true;
                  }
              }
              if ( found != true ){
                  System.out.println("Song does not exist.");
              }
              break;
    case 'B':
    case 'b': System.out.print("Enter song artist: ");
              String searchArtist = input.nextLine();
              for (Song i : songList){
                  if (i.getArtist().equals(searchArtist)){
                      System.out.println(i);
                      found = true;
                  }
              }
              if ( found != true ){
                  System.out.println("Song does not exist.");
              }
              break;
    case 'C':
    case 'c': System.out.print("Enter song album: ");
              String searchAlbum = input.nextLine();
              for (Song i : songList){
                  if (i.getAlbum().equals(searchAlbum)){
                      System.out.println(i);
                      found = true;
                  }
              }
              if ( found != true ){
                  System.out.println("Song does not exist.");
              }
              break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `String searchArtist = input.next();` to `String searchArtist = input.nextLine();`

Using `.next()` you are unable to input more than 1 word. It will stop capturing further input upon receiving a space.

I suggest you to change all 3 input scanning method to `.nextLine()`.

Comment: I am sure this is the solution! But, now it is skipping over the for loop and it is just saying it does not exist. Its not even letting me input anything when "Enter song title: " comes up

Comment: @Shorty you mean after changing your codes, it becomes buggy or it was already buggy before the changes?

Comment: I changed all the inputs to .nextLine() like you said and now it won't let me input anything it just skips the for loop and says does not exist.

Comment: you should step through the code to help you find where the error is occuring

Comment: @shorty there is no need to change every part of the code to `nextLine()`. You only need to change it where you need to receive the song name, artist and albulm name. Changes in these 3 areas won't affect your code to the extend of denying your input.

Comment: @Shorty You might have make changes at your side which you did not show here. For example, using `input` to receive `integer` input. That can cause problem such as skipping subsequent input. The problem probably lies in `MenuInputCheck()` method which is not shown here. I highly suspect you used variable `input` to capture numbers within `MenuInputCheck()`.

Comment: Thanks fo your help! I was able to fix it by also changing the menuOption to input.nextLine as well.